# PHP: Calling a specific name in a form from another file

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, fetch

So I am having trouble setting a name in a form as a variable. I am trying to do this on another page but without using the include, require functions cause when I use them it fetches the whole other file. My question is, is there a way to call a specific name in another file without fetching the whole file. Here is an example of what I am truing to do.

This is fetching the form names "Mitsubishi1", "Lancer1" and "2000 - 2007". It obviously will not work because those names have been undefined in the current file. It is also fetching the relevant data from the database.

```
if ($selectMake1 == $_POST["Mitsubishi1"] && $selectModel1 == $_POST["Lancer1"] && $selectYear1 == $_POST["2000 - 2007"])
 $fetchMitFirst = mysql_query("SELECT Max_Speed FROM CarSpecifications WHERE id=2")
```

This is in the other file where I want to fetch these names but without fetching the whole file.

```
<option name="Mitsubishi1">Mitsubishi</option>
<option name="Lancer1">Lancer</option>
<option name="2000 - 2007">2000 - 2007</option>
```

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Only using get to go to another file with instantied variables done and running your code.

Other mode will need ajax.

Comment: So i'd probably need ajax? To run it all in one file

Comment: or he can use session variable

Comment: Sry Dale, your post it's ok, GET or POST will work. I didn't understand very well what you want. Can be more specific?

If your frontend form executes before backend (code above), will work smoothly.

Comment: only `<select>` bears the name attribute, not `<option>`.

Comment: Thats ok. So if i put in the require or include functions it would get the names but also all the rest of the html. The reason I think it's not defined is because when i try to run it i get the following error per variable and name.  
                                                                                                              
Notice: Undefined index: Mitsubishi1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SelectDropDowns/Page2.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined variable: selectMake1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SelectDropDowns/Page2.php on line 9

Comment: Option i thought does work with name. It works with another part of my php when fetching what is selected in my dropdown.

Comment: Option works with VALUE, with a SELECT as container with a name in it!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: @mJehanno pass simple values by SESSION it's a bad practice and you should avoid that 

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160947/should-session-variables-be-avoided

Comment: If the variables selectMake1, selectModel1 and selectYear1 are set in another php file, can they be reset once those are used? Sorry i'm quite new to php.